# Git diff cached does nothing

Tags: git, github

Here is where I'm at:

1. Created a new repo on GitHub
2. Initialized (git add .) my working directory locally on my PC
3. commited (git commit -m) all changes to stage
4. Made another change by adding a new .png file
5. Did another git commit -m
6. Now I want to see a list of all staged files that will be pushed before I actually push them for the first time (or really at any time) to the remote repo (https//.../../).  So I assumed there'd be 2 commit full of changes to show for

If I tried to `commit again (#3)`, it shows `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.  So I must have committed successfully last time I assume is why it's saying this.

When I do a `git status` I get `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

BUT when I try to type `git diff --cached --name-only` or `git diff --staged` in terminal in OS X it did nothing.  I just get the command prompt after running that command again.

Am I missing something here?  I've searched for stuff on git diff but I must be blind.

Comment: Isn't your new GitHub repository blank? That should mean you're pushing all the files you've committed.

Comment: sorry I updated my post.  Yes also I know that's what would happen but l also like to double-check just to see sometimes...especially after doing 2 consecutive local commits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `git diff --cached` will show you the difference between the repository and the index (the place where files are staged by `git add` before they are committed to the repository).  It does not look at files in your working directory, nor does it compare differences between revisions in the repository.

If you want to see how your local repository differs from the upstream repository, first make sure your local cache of the remote repository is up-to-date:

```
git remote update
```

And then compare your local branch to the corresponding branch in the remote repository:

```
git diff --name-only mybranch origin/mybranch
```

..assuming that your remote is named `origin`, which it probably is.

**Update**

If you are pushing to an empty remote repository, then the answer to "what files will be pushed?" is "all of them", and there is nothing to run `diff` against.

You can run `git ls-files` to see a list of all files in the repository.

In my earlier example, `mybranch` would be the name of a branch, such as `master` or `bug/1234` or `this-is-a-nifty-feature`, and the example assumes that you are pushing the local branch to a branch of the same name in the remote repository.

**Update 2**

You asked:

> my remote branch is a url so what is origin...the uri/[repo name]? so
>   origin is the uri? And what would I refer to as the name of my local
>   branch?

A git repository can be associated with one or more remote repositories, called "remotes".  If you clone a remote repository:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:larsks/sandbox.git
```

You will end up with a remote called `origin` referring to this repository:

```
$ cd sandbox
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:larsks/sandbox.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:larsks/sandbox.git (push)
```

Your local branch is, initially, named `master`, so your initial push would look like:

```
$ git push origin master
```

This asks git to push your local `master` branch to the `master` branch of the remote repository referred to as `origin`.

But you can create new branches using the "git checkout -b" or "git branch" commands.  There is a lot of documentation out there that will probably provide a better overview than I can in this answer.  I would start with [The Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: I just want to see what's about to be pushed from my local stage to the remote repo.  This is the first push I'm doing for a brand new blank repo

Comment: my remote branch is a url so what is origin...the uri/[repo name]? so origin is the uri?  And what would I refer to as the name of my local branch?

Comment: maybe what I want is git diff --stat --cached [remote/branch] which would give me list of files to be pushed?  I tried that and I'm not specifying the remote/branch correctly probably because I tried "git diff --stat --cached https://myname@bitbucket.org/somedirectory/myRepoName.git.  I lied I'm using BitBucket but doesn't matter

Comment: Since you have an empty remote repository, none of the `diff` commands suggested are going to get you anything useful.  They will pretty much all do something useful after you have completed your initial push.  Until that point, the answer to your question is basically `git ls-files`.

Comment: thanks I get all that which you just updated your answer with.  I guess what I'm looking for (to see) is that what if I did the first commit.  But did not commit the .png file (un-commmitted).  I'd want to set a list of committed files (committed to stage to be pushed) only, and so I'd expect to be able to see a list of the files committed to stage only which means those are the files that will ultimately be pushed.

Comment: also I thought "git add" initializes your working directory and makes your files trackable so that you can stage them later on.  Add doesn't actually stage the files...  The commit stages them right?

Comment: You are still mixing vocabulary. "Committed to stage" doesn't mean anything. You can see the staging area as a place where you add all the changes you want to include in your next commit. Typically `git add` on an untracked file or modified file will place the files/changes on the stage. Committing is defining a new snapshot based on previous commit and changes in the staging area. I recommend a book, such as https://git-scm.com/

Comment: yea definitely loosing my head, I need sleep.  Right. I have read the book I just need to go back and re-read, it's been a while.

Comment: Then I'm asking how can I see the latest committed snapshot (list of files in that which are about to be pushed).

Comment: I think we've largely answered that question.  If it's your first push to an empty repository, just run `git ls-files`.  Otherwise, use something like the `git diff` command I suggested in the first part of my answer

Comment: tried 
UPDATE

I tried  `git diff --name-only master origin/remoteRepoName.git` and got "unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: `git ls-files` only lists untracked files (and only those) when you use the `-o` option. Also, better to remove snapshot from your git vocabulary, it was just me trying to find an analogy for explaining the tree, which is the complete, recursive state of the git files arranged in a tree.

Comment: so then why doesn't git diff --cached work for me?  I think that's what I'm after here.

Comment: it's already answered quite well in the first line of this answer. `git diff --cached` basically shows a diff between the last commit and stuff you have already staged. It has nothing to do with comparing 2 commits.

Comment: @WeDoTDD I'll add another answer to give some more info. Glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

Since an image is worth 1000 words, and I don't want to re-invent the wheel, allow me to link one of the illustrations of the https://git-scm.com book, showing the life-cycle of a file in git and showing the role of the cache. I admit there are a couple things I dislike about this picture but it will serve this purpose well.

[image]

If you've done some modifications and are in the middle of staging ("slang" for saying "adding to the cache") some of them with `git add` and the more granular `git add -p`, then the commands `git diff` and `git diff --cached` are ways to see what has already been added to the cache and what can still be added. By added here, I mean `git add`-wise, so adding an untracked file, or adding a modification.

- `git diff`: shows modifications that you **can** stage with `git add`. Note that this only applies to the "stage the file" arrow, it doesn't list untracked files.
- `git diff --cached`: shows **only** the diff between things already staged and the previous commit.

In your case, `git diff --cached` shows nothing, because you have already committed everything that was in your staging area, and have not added anything since then.

The reason the option is called `--cached` is because the git staging area was originally called the `cache`. You'll also encounter the term `index`.

@larsks's answer is correct, I just wanted to give this alternative picture in reaction to the comments which followed his answer.